My super key no longer open the launcher, how do I reenable this?
I'm running 23.10; yesterday I suffered hypoglycaemia and, apparently, hit a lot of keys on the keyboard. Unfortunately I can't say which keys, or even guess at the order in which I hit them. After I got myself sorted out I realised that my super key – both of them, but I don't think I ever tried to use the right one before yesterday evening – no longer opens the launcher. The icon remains in the upper left so this is merely an inconvenience, but this isn't the first time (the last time was on 23.04).
Previously I took the somewhat nuclear option of reinstalling the OS, but I'd rather not do that again if at all possible.
If more details are needed I'll do my best to provide them, but I'm not sure what specifically is needed.

Is the option on Keyboard & Mouse -> Overview shortcut  set to Left Super in GNOME Tweaks??

It is, yes; though pressing left super does nothing (I switched it to right super to test, and that also does nothing).
